# Share data on Weibo and QQ internation in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, weibo

I am trying to share data on QQ internation and Weibo, but not getting such a good way to post data on this messengers, i tried a lot for sharing data on weibo and qq internation but not getting result.

```
  guide me to correct way and which is the good way to share data on this both messegner.
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the SDK's they offer. Third-party service providers encapsulate their services on platforms such as iPhone in special SDK (software development kit) so you can easily talk to their servers.

[QQ iOS SDK](http://wiki.open.qq.com/wiki/mobile/SDK%E4%B8%8B%E8%BD%BD)

[Weibo iOS SDK](http://open.weibo.com/wiki/IOS_SDK)

Comment: Hello thanks for reply.. Weibo sharing :- Done but still getting issue in QQ, i got the sdk and demo for sharing on QQ, but when i am trying to share - in safari login page open and when i enter the credential the page redirect and got the error like , "The Requested URL is invalid". i stuck at here. have you any suggetion.?

Comment: I haven't worked with the QQ SDK and cannot tell you what is wrong. Regardless, this seems to be a separate question on its own right, and I don't think anyone can help without your code, error message and such.

Answer (score 0):

Try [MonkeyKing](https://github.com/nixzhu/MonkeyKing) library.

> MonkeyKing helps you post messages to Chinese Social Networks, without
>   their buggy SDKs.
>
> MonkeyKing use the same analysis process of openshare, support share
>   Text, URL, Image, Audio, and Video to WeChat, QQ or Weibo. MonkeyKing
>   also can post message to Weibo by webpage. (Note that Auido and Video
>   are only specifically for WeChat or QQ)
>
> One more thing: MonkeyKing supports OAuth.